# Charles Proxy blocking internet sharing when off

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, proxy

I can successfully use Charles proxy for my iPhone device through internet sharing via wifi. I also successfully installed a SSL certificate on my device to decrypt secure traffic. When I activate HTTP proxy on my device as directed on the Charles proxy website everything works perfectly.

However whenever I turn HTTP Proxy off on my device, I no longer receive traffic (this is the problem). This happens whether Charles is running or not. It happens after restarting my mobile device and notebook. I've turned sharing internet on and off both with Charles on and off, recording on and off. I've even tried removing the SSL certificate on device. I can't use my internet sharing without Charles actively viewing my traffic (which upsets many of my apps). I was able to accomplish this in the past.

Comment: What's the question?  What is your expected result?  Consider rewriting your question so that it clearly states what the problem is and what you would like resolved.

Comment: @Allan The problem is charles is blocking the internet sharing when its off. It shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Allan I updated my question to show what line expressed the problem